# How to measure NFC RSSI in android?

Tags: android, rss, nfc, rssi, signal-strength

I am trying to get the signal strength between an NFC tag and an NFC reader. I am using Android beam for this communication between two mobile-phones and do not know if I can get RSSI values from these mobile-phones via android programming?

if no, is there any way to calculate NFC RSSI?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer is No and No.

A lot/most of the time with NFC you are not dealing with anything close to the Hardware, especially with the Deprecated Android Beam.
Instead you are dealing with an OS service and that does not expose any details like that.

I'm also not sure why you would want the signal strength as the typical transmission range is up to 4cm, so trying to use it as an estimate of distance would be show very little difference.